# Mongoose statically linking with libssl?

Tags: c++, mongoose-web-server, libssl

I want to compile moongose with static library of libssl . 
I have given .a file with -L option. 
But still it is loading .so file. 
why ?
how can I force it to use static lib ?

Comment: Is the *.a really the static library and not the import library?

Comment: see http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/source/browse/mongoose.c line no 3562 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run compilation under `strace`, to look where .a file is being searched and why .so is loaded instead.

**EDIT**
By default moongose loads SSL dynamically. To change this compile it with `NO_SSL_DL` macro. Add `-DNO_SSL_DL` to compilation command line. See [this link](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/issues/detail?id=171#c7).

Comment: please check code see code.google.com/p/mongoose/source/browse/mongoose.c line no 3562 they are calling load_dll

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need to recompile moongose with NO_SSL_DL macro. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/issues/detail?id=171#c7)

Comment: I want ssl support . but I don't want to use dynamic lib, I want to  use static lib.

Comment: OK, link statically as you did and also compile with `NO_SSL_DL` macro. Than you shold have ssl support statically - I have not tested it. Also note that you should give .a file with `-l` option - [man gcc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).